# How to get a user by username in MODx?

Tags: php, modx

I need to get a user object in MODx using the username. Or the profile by username. How can I do that?

I know how to do it by id.

I'm using MODx REvo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$user = $modx->getObject('modUser', array(
    'username' => $username,
));

if ($user) {
    $profile = $user->getOne('Profile');
}
```